# How can I get the SQL from a query object in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

How can I get the SQL used to generate a cfquery object?  If I cfdump the object, it shows it having an "SQL" property, which contains the actual query.  Turning on debugging won't help me because I am making an API call, so output is not HTML and debug info would break it. I'm just trying to debug exactly what query is being executed.

```
<cfquery name="tableElements" datasource="TestSQLServer">
SELECT * FROM tableElements
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#tableElements#" /> <!--- Shows object having "SQL" property --->
<cfoutput>SQL: #tableElements.SQL#</cfoutput> <!--- Error: Element SQL is undefined in TABLEELEMENTS. --->
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add a 'result' attribute to your cfquery.  The SQL is in the result struct, not the query variable.

Comment: Dang it Todd! You beat me to it while I was double checking my code!

Comment: You could also technically dip down into Java and get it:

<cfdump var="#q.getMetadata().getExtendedMetaData().sql#" />

Comment: Darn it. Beat me too. I was going mention extended metadata. But with you pointing out the simpler result attribute, I figured why bother (We are going to have to start tinkering with your keyboard or something ..;)

Comment: If you have parameters, this SQL will have a bunch of question marks for each param. Is it possible to get the final SQL, with the params inserted into the SQL?

Answer (score 23):

```
<cfquery name="tableElements" datasource="TestSQLServer" result="r">
SELECT * FROM tableElements
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#tableElements#" /> <!--- Shows object having "SQL" property --->
<cfoutput>SQL: #r.SQL#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: You could put <pre> tags around #r.sql# so the query displays formatted.

Answer (score 10):

Personally I like to have some SQL that has all the parameters inserted into it (rather than the ? question marks). This way I can just copy and paste the SQL to run a query on the database. To do this, I get a result (as mentioned in other comments), then use this function...

```
<cffunction name="getRealSQL" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="qryResult" type="any">
    <cfset realSQL = arguments.qryResult.sql>
    <cfloop array="#arguments.qryResult.sqlParameters#" index="a">
        <cfscript>
            if (NOT isNumeric(a)) a = "'#a#'";
            realSQL = Replace(realSQL, "?", a);
        </cfscript>
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn realSQL>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I should not that this may not work properly with dates.

Comment: Also doesn't work correctly if there may be literal ? chars the sql, i.e., ones inside single quotes.

Comment: Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208210/how-can-i-get-the-sql-from-a-query-object-in-coldfusion/22849629#comment4551585_4208519) comment we can skip adding Result attribute to CFQuery making life easier :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the result attribute of cfquery.  Specify a variable name and that will have a key called sql with your sql.

Answer (score 3):

If you are cfdump-ing a structure holding queries (not what Kip needs but I needed the SQL), use the `metainfo="yes"`. W/o yields only the records of the query[image]...

```
<cfset stx={}>
<cfquery name="stx.q" datasource="myDataSource">
    select emp_id from employees where 1=2
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#stx.q#">
<cfdump var="#stx.q#" metainfo="yes">
```

[image: examples of cfdump of a query in a struct without and with metainfo attribute]

Answer (score 2):

If dumping debug output within the regular output would break things, i always use `<cfdump var="#myvar#" output="c:\filename.html">` 
That way, the dump ends up in a separate HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to turn debugging on via the CF administrator?  That will give you a rolling list of every query (including the SQL statements) that are being called in a given page.

Comment: "Turning on debugging won't help me because I am making an API call, so output is not HTML and debug info would break it."